# How to remove \n and empty string in a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-science-experience

I have a data frame and one column consists of list value. I have attached the picture in excel format and data frame as well.

```
column
"[
""Hello""
]"
"[
""Hello"", 
 ""Hi""
]"
"[
""Hello"", 
 ""Hi"",
 """"
]"
"[
"""",
""Hello"", 
 ""Hi""
]"
"[
""Hello"",
""""
]"
"[
"""",
""Hello""

]"
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPkrk.png)][1][image]The column value looks like

```
column
------
[\n "Hello" \n]
[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]
[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n, \n ""\n]
[\n ""\n, \n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]
[\n "Hello" \n, \n ""\n]
[\n ""\n, \n "Hello" \n]
```

So, I want to remove `\n` and `""` from the list and have value as

```
column
------
["Hello"]
["Hello", "Hi"]
["Hello", "Hi"]
["Hello", "Hi"]
["Hello"]
["Hello"]
```

So, how can we obtain following result using pandas and python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to handle the input data that you have because that is not correctly formatted Python. However, I think there are a couple of ways to solve the problem.

## Input data (as correct Python)

```py
column = [
    ['\n "Hello" \n'],
    ['\n "Hello"', '\n "Hi"\n'],
    ['\n "Hello"',' \n "Hi"\n', '\n ""\n'],
    ['\n ""\n', '\n "Hello"', '\n "Hi"\n'],
    ['\n "Hello" \n', '\n ""\n'],
    ['\n ""\n', '\n "Hello" \n']
]
```

## Code: First `map` then List Comprehension

The `map` removes the whitespace including the newline `\n` characters. The list comprehension then removes the empty entries from each row (`""`).

```py
def stripper(text):
    return text.strip().strip('"')

for row in column:
    output = list(map(stripper, row))
    print([i for i in output if i])
```

## Output

```
['Hello']
['Hello', 'Hi']
['Hello', 'Hi']
['Hello', 'Hi']
['Hello']
['Hello']
```

Note that the end result has single quotes rather than double quotes. Let me know if this matters for what you're doing.

## For fun

Just for fun, I took your input data absolutely literally, and wrote a set of replacements to result in exactly the output you have in the question.

### Input data

```py
column = r"""[\n "Hello" \n]
[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]
[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n, \n ""\n]
[\n ""\n, \n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]
[\n "Hello" \n, \n ""\n]
[\n ""\n, \n "Hello" \n]""".splitlines()
```

### Code

```py
for row in column:
    print(row.replace('\\n "', '"').replace('" \\n', '"').replace('""\\n, ', '').replace(', ""\\n', '').replace('"\\n', ''))
```

### Output

```
["Hello"]
["Hello", "Hi]
["Hello", "Hi]
["Hello", "Hi]
["Hello"]
["Hello"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So, when I tried to do 
```
for row in df.column:
          df['column']=row.replace('\n','"')
```

I got an error message
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`.
I have been getting this error all day.

Comment: You are applying the `.replace()` to the `list`. You need to apply the `.replace()` to each member of the list.

Comment: what is the correct code to apply to replace each member of the list? I tried that but failed

Comment: Use the first one at the top: `map`. Write a function that performs the replace, and then map each row to that function. Look at the code that I wrote as the example.

Comment: So, I did  
`def stripper(text):
    return text.replace('\n', '"')

for row in df.column:
    output = list(map(stripper, row))
    df['column']=[i for i in output if i]
`
It returned with error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: You haven't provided any code, so it's not easy to help you. Can you provide the whole code your using and a sample data input?

Comment: I have edited the question and paste the image for better question - @Utkonos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249293/discussion-between-utkonos-and-bad-coder).

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example that you provided with a dataframe `df` with column name `column`, we will use the following code snippet

```
def remove_empty_line(row):
    updated_list = list()
    for elem in row:
        updated_list.append(elem.replace("\n", "").strip())
return updated_list

df["column"] = df["column"].apply(lambda row: remove_empty_line(row))
```

Now you can check your df with `df.head()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd


# Recreating data.
column = [
    '[\n "Hello" \n]',
    '[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]',
    '[\n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n, \n ""\n]',
    '[\n ""\n, \n "Hello", \n "Hi"\n]',
    '[\n "Hello" \n, \n ""\n]',
    '[\n ""\n, \n "Hello" \n]',
]
df = pd.DataFrame({"column": column})

out = df.assign(
    # We map the following operations to "column".
    column=df.column
    .map(
        # Iterate over each value -- each will become a list of literals (in this case, strings).
        lambda x: [
            # We unpack the filtered values into the list.
            *filter(
                # Check the bool value of each item produced by `literal_eval`, keeping only those that are True.
                bool, literal_eval(x)
            )
        ]
    )
)
print(out)
```

```
        column
0      [Hello]
1  [Hello, Hi]
2  [Hello, Hi]
3  [Hello, Hi]
4      [Hello]
5      [Hello]
```